# VBScript / PowerShell , how to write a script to secure Windows Registry

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, registry

I wanted to use WScript.Shell object to secure a registry path , e.g HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Registration\UserProfile.

So the objective is that , create a new permission for 'everyone' , and deny the following: Delete , Create SubKeys etc.

Googled a lot , and didn't get a deal on my specific problem , could anyone give me a hint on this point ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help

```
$acl = Get-Acl "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Registration\UserProfile"
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("mycomp\everyone","FullControl","Allow") # or deny...
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl |Set-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Registration\UserProfile"
```

To add or remove an access rule you need to create the rule as an object of type RegistryAccessRule, and then either create or remove the rule from the ACL with the SetAccessRule() or RemoveAccessRule() methods

Just for have another example: [Set-ACL on registry key](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/09/29/set-acl-on-registry-key.aspx/)

Comment: Get-Acl works only for files i guess , when i try an existing registry path , it says: Can't find path XXX , because it doesn't exist

Comment: Get-Acl works in registry and other PSDrive. try Get-pssdrive and you can see HKLM and HKCU in the list. Maybe you registry path doesn't exist or is wrong?

Comment: You have to write in "" if path have spaces on it.